# ArchCraft/Manjaro won't boot from USB

Tags: usb, arch-linux, lenovo-laptop, bootable-media, manjaro

I am running a Lenovo X1 Carbon. I used Rufus to write a USB(16GB Storage "CruzerBlade").
I open the Lenovo Boot menu where I select to boot from my USB, but it doesn't work and goes back to the Boot Menu.

The Manjaro installation only works in `DD` mode, however, for ArchCraft I used `ISO`.
Both times I formatted my USB with the `FAT32` option, **not `NTFS`**, yet it still does not work.

Edit: I currently also have the latest version of Ubuntu installed, although I'm looking to switch to either of the mentioned Operating Systems

Can someone help and explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If it works in "DD mode" use it. Or use any other tool. They all use dd by default, except Rufus.

Comment: @ChanganAuto No, currently neither DD mode works, nor ISO. Any other ideas?

Comment: Checksum to make sure the ISO isn't corrupt and use a different USB stick.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I will try what method you've offered, thanks for now.

Comment: @ChanganAuto How do I checksum? The method on the ArchCraft website doesn't work, it says there is no such file(The iso).

Comment: It's probably accurate if you aren't in the same folder where the ISO was downloaded.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I was, the file extensions didn't seem to match